# C++Builder does not call destructor on throw-catch-continue

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, c++builder, destructor

For code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ConstrCalls=0, DestrCalls=0;

struct Z
{
    Z() { ConstrCalls++; }
    ~Z() { DestrCalls++; }
};

int main(int argc, char**)
{
   bool Startup= true;

   do
   {
      Z z;

      try
      {
          if( Startup )
          {
              Startup= false;
              throw( 1 );
          }
          else
          {
              break;
          }
      }
      catch(int)
      {
          continue;
      }
   }
   while(true);

   printf( "ConstrCalls=%d DestrCalls=%d", ConstrCalls, DestrCalls);
   return 0;
}
```

- g++ output is **`"ConstrCalls=2 DestrCalls=2"`**, ok
- Embarcadero C++Builder 2010, C++Builder 10 Seattle output is **`"ConstrCalls=2 DestrCalls=1"`**, that is after throw-catch-continue destructor was not called!

Can C++Builder works right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly...

> the C++Builder 6, RAD Studio 2009 and XE7 Update 1, C++ compiler generates bad exception handling code (and in all likelihood all compilers in between--those are the compilers I current have access to). When an exception is thrown, the stack unwind code has been observed to:
>
> - Crash with an access violation
> - Fail to execute destructors when it should
> - Leak memory
> - Fire destructors twice
>
> This makes it impossible to produce reliable, exception-safe, C++ software with this compiler.

Take a look at [C++ compiler exception handling is completely broken](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13173) for further details.

This is from the section "*Not Firing Destructors When It Should*":

> The following Button `OnClick` event handler constructs temporary `Count` objects only within the `try`/`catch` scope. Count objects keep track of the number of live instances in the count variable.
>
> As an invariant the number of Count instances should be 0 following the `try`/`catch`. Instead this fails with BAD STACK UNWIND.
>
> ```
> static int count = 0;
>
> struct Count {
>     Count() { ++count; }
>     Count(const Count& rhs) { ++count; }
>     ~Count( ) { --count; }
> };
>
> static int __fastcall destructorNotFired(int i=0, Count c=Count() ) {
>     throw Exception( "DESTRUCTOR NOT FIRED" );
> }
>
> void __fastcall TExceptionBugTestForm::ButtonDestructorNotFiredClick(TObject *Sender)
> {
>     assert(count == 0);
>
>     try {
>         destructorNotFired( destructorNotFired() );
>     } catch ( Exception& e ) {
>     }
>
>     if (count != 0) {
>         ShowMessage( "BAD STACK UNWIND" );
>     }
>
>     assert(count == 0);
> }
> ```

(very similar to your code).

Exception handling works well compiling code with `clang++` (only 64bit for C++Builder != XE10).

Comment: Great answer, thank you. <ul> - Do you know what Embarcadero think about of this error?</ul>